# Looking for proof-without-words of Bezout's identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, visualization, proof-without-words

I'm looking for a ["proof-without-words"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) of [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) (for integers).

Does anyone know of one?

Comment: You may be interested in some of the [pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) in this Wiki article.

Comment: How do you express coprimality without words? I'm not even sure of that...